# Need help translating small code block from VBA to Python

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, vba

I need help from someone to translate a small piece of code from VBA to Python, due to the fact that the company I am working for has upgraded from ArcGIS 9.3.1 to 10.0 and VBA is no longer supported. The code block is as follows:

```
static x0 as double, y0 as double  
dim pPoint as IPoint  
set pPoint = [Shape]  
x = pPoint.X   
y = pPoint.Y  
d = sqr((x-x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2)    
x0 = x   
y0= y
```

This is used with the calculate field tool inside model builder and as far as I can tell retrieves info about two points and calculates the difference in distance between them. I have attempted a few translations on my own with little success using `!shape.firstpoint.x!`, `!shape.firstpoint.y!`

Unfortunately my knowledge is lacking and I need some assistance. If you are able to help, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you post links to your translation attempts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do it (place it in the `code block` section):

```
def calc_distance(shape, x0, y0):
    point = shape.getPart(0)
    X = point.X
    Y = point.Y 
    d = math.sqrt(pow(X-x0,2) + pow(Y-y0,2)) 
    return d
```

The `Expression` should be:

```
calc_distance(!SHAPE!, 10000, 10000)
```

However, you'll need to pass the second X and Y you're comparing from in place of the two *10,000* numbers I've put into the expression. Its not clear in your VBA where you're getting those two coordinates from (they may just be 0).

Comment: I am using shapefiles with a few thousand points each, they are GPS data from cattle collars.  I presume that it uses the FID of the points and just retrieves the coordinates in order (eg. distance between point 1 & 2, 2 & 3, 3 & 4... etc).  Unfortunately I did not create the original model or write the code, so I am trying to comprehend it as best as I can myself.  This code block is just a small part of a model that creates lots of fields in an attribute table and then populates them with the 'calculate field' tool.  I will try your code today and see where I can get.  Thanks again.